# How to Remove Group Header / Footer

Tags: visual-studio, report, reporting, rdlc

I created a Group with a Header and a Footer. Then i tried to delete just the header, but it looks like there is no way to do so.

### Here are a Sample:

**First :** Creating my group header and footer
[image: Creating my group header and footer]

**Secound :** trying to delete my header
[image]

**Result :** it removed all rows in this group
[image]

---

### Question

> Is there a way to delete only the header row without creating a new Tablix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Row Group Section.

Click Row Group `Detail`,
[image]

Click on marked, Here you will find Delete Group as well as what you want.

Comment: As far as i can see, there is no option to remove a header or footer of the group

Comment: Just select header row without Group then delete row.

Comment: ahh ok, found it. to delete the footer i just have to right click on the row header but to delete header i have to right click on a Cell in this row

Answer (score 0):

Right click on any of the cells in the row you would like to delete and then select "Delete Rows". That's easy ;-)